# Get all users with specific role using discord.js

Tags: javascript, discord, discord.js, bots

I'm getting `RangeError [BITFIELD_INVALID]: Invalid bitfield flag or number: undefined.` with this code. Can someone help me with what's `undefined` here?

I'm using discord.js v13.6.0.

```js
require('dotenv').config();
const token = process.env.bot_token;

const { Client, Intents } = require("discord.js")
const client = new Client({
  intents: [
    Intents.FLAGS.GUILDS,
    Intents.FLAGS.GUILD_MESSAGES,
    Intents.NON_PRIVILEGED,
    Intents.GUILD_MEMBERS
  ]
});

const prefix = '!getUserByRole';

client.on("messageCreate", (message) =>{
    if(!message.content.startsWith(prefix) || message.author.bot || message.author.id) return;
    const args = message.content.slice(prefix.length).split(/ +/);
    const roleId = args[1];
    message.guild.members.fetch().then((members)=>{
        members.filter(mmbr => mmbr.roles.cache.get(roleId)).map(m => {
            console.log(m.user.tag, m.user.id);
        });
    })
})

client.login(token);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In discord.js v13 `Intents.ALL`, `Intents.NON_PRIVILEGED`, and `Intents.PRIVILEGED` have all been removed to discourage bad practices. It means you need to remove `Intents.NON_PRIVILEGED`.

Also, there is no `Intents.GUILD_MEMBERS`, it should be [`Intents.FLAGS.GUILD_MEMBERS`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/Intents?scrollTo=s-FLAGS). So you'll need to update your code like this:

```js
const client = new Client({
  intents: [
    Intents.FLAGS.GUILDS,
    Intents.FLAGS.GUILD_MESSAGES,
    Intents.FLAGS.GUILD_MEMBERS,
  ],
});
```

Comment: Thank you!
Can you also help me with this?
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71491286/mass-role-assign-to-users-discord-js-v13/71492236#71492236