# Mass role assign to users (discord.js v13)

Tags: javascript, discord, discord.js

This code assigns role to a list of users separated by new line, but only users in cache.
How can I implement message.guild.members.fetch() to this code to assign role to all users?

```
//command
!roleAssign @role
name#1234
name#2234
name#3234
```

```
const roleAssign = function(message){
  const Role = message.mentions.roles.first();
  // split by new line
  const users = message.content.slice(prefix.length).split(/\r?\n/).slice(1);
  const success = [];

  users.forEach(user => {
    const u = client.users.cache.find(u => u.tag === user);
    if(u){
      const userId = u.id;
      // person with the userID
      let person = message.guild.members.cache.get(userId);
      // give role to person

      try{
        person.roles.add(Role)
      }
      catch(e){console.error(e)};

      if(person.roles.cache.has(Role.id)){
        success.push(user);
      }
      }
  });

  message.channel.send(`Added role ${Role.name} to\n${success.map(user => user).join("\n")}`);
}
```

I tried this but got `TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'find')`

```
message.guild.members.fetch().then((members)=>{
  message.cache.find(u => u.tag === user);
})
```

Comment: Don't spam the API... that's a bad idea

Comment: Can you show me other ways to mass assign role? I'm a discord noob

Answer (score 0):

```
let members = await message.guild.members.fetch()

members.filter(user => !user.bot).tap(message.guild => {

})
```